# Javascript - create a new object that mimics primitive data type

Tags: javascript, object, constructor

I need to create an new Object in Javascript which should return a number value. 
What I expect is:

```js
var Currency = function(args) {
    return args*Currency.prototype.multiple;
}

Currency.prototype.multiple = 1000;
Currency.prototype.Locale='en-IN';
Currency.prototype.currency= 'INR';
Currency.prototype.paise = function(){
    return  (Currency.prototype.args*Currency.prototype.multiple);
};
Currency.prototype.show = function(){
    return (this.valueOf()/Currency.prototype.multiple).toLocaleString(Currency.prototype.Locale, { style: 'currency', currency: Currency.prototype.currency });
};

var num = new Currency(5);
console.log(num) //5000
```

But what I got is a object

```
currency{}
```

How to achieve my intended result?

Comment: Please provide more context. What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: Your code is kind of weird, you can avoid creating an object if you omit the `new` keyword. Just call `Currency` like a normal function.

Comment: @FelixKling I am trying to create a new Data type 'Currency' which has its own properties. Currency is always a number but it should be multiplied by 1000. I dont want to access the value of the function using obj.value. Instead I want to access its value by simply obj(Like primitive data types)

Comment: If come from a classical programming language, I would recommend creating classes using the newer `class` syntax introduced in ES2015. [Check here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes) but note that only using this syntax to create javascript objects doesn't show you how the language works

Answer (score 0):

When you create an instance with `new` it automatically returns the newly created object from constructor. It is not recommended to override it unless you are sure about it. Also note that if you return a non-object like a number it will override that and just return the newly created object. If you want to override this you will have to return an object itself, like `return {value: args*Currency.prototype.multiple}` but you have to add your logic to keep reference to your newly created object to use later, like accessing the `currency`.

In your case, you can just have a `value` for each currency and set it in constructor which you can later access with `myObject.value`

To use it as number when it demands use as a number you can use [valueOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/valueOf#Overriding_valueOf_for_custom_objects) as @Xufox mentioned

> With the preceding code(valueOf) in place, any time an object of type
>   myNumberType is used in a context where it is to be represented as a
>   primitive value, JavaScript automatically calls the function defined
>   in the preceding code.

```
var num = new Currency(5);
console.log(num+100 + num.currency);//5100INR
```

```js
var Currency = function(args) {
    this.value = args*Currency.prototype.multiple;
}

Currency.prototype.multiple = 1000;
Currency.prototype.Locale='en-IN';
Currency.prototype.currency= 'INR';
Currency.prototype.paise = function(){
    return  (Currency.prototype.args*Currency.prototype.multiple);
};
Currency.prototype.show = function(){
    return (this.valueOf()/Currency.prototype.multiple).toLocaleString(Currency.prototype.Locale, { style: 'currency', currency: Currency.prototype.currency });
};

Currency.prototype.valueOf = function(){
  return this.value;
}

var num = new Currency(5);
console.log(num.value + num.currency) //5000
console.log(num+100 + num.currency);
var num2 = new Currency(50);
console.log(num2.value + num2.currency) //5000
```

Comment: Thanks:)  I  want the object to behave as native data type. i.e., Instead of 'num.value' to access my value I want 'num' itself to store my data(Like primitive data types).

Comment: @Avinash You can define a `valueOf` function property on the `prototype` that returns the value. `num` will then still be an object, but you can use it as a number.